# Python list unique

Tags: python-3.x

How can you access the element '5' from this list = `[0 ,[ 6, 3], [4, 6, [7, 5] ] ]` ?

The options we have :
1) `return list[1][2]` 
2) `return list[len(list)-1][1]`
3) `return list[2][len(list[2])-1][1]`
4) `list[2][2][2]`

Comment: It is easy to test the potential solutions you list, to see if they give the correct output or not. Could you maybe add more information about what specific parts of these options you are confused about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List:

```
 [0 ,[ 6, 3], [4, 6, [7, 5] ] ]
```

list[2]:

```
[4, 6, [7, 5] ]
```

list[2][2]:

```
[7, 5]
```

list[2][2][1]:

```
5

list[2][len(list[2])-1][1] == list[2][2][1]
```